# mysql - replicating to db with a different name

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave, master

Can a mysql db named statsDb on server1.example.com be replicated to a db named newNameDb on server2.example.com ? server2.example.com already has a statsDb. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You would want to use --replicate-rewrite-db:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-rewrite-db

Comment: +1 never knew that! Useful link!